# What happen if accidentally move a soft link followed by "/"?

Tags: symlink, mv

I created a soft link to the current directory,

```
$ ln -s "$PWD" math
```

I then wanted to move it to another directory.

```
$ mv math/ ~/dirlinks/maths/
```

I then realized I should

```
$ mv math ~/dirlinks/maths/
```

So I ctrl-c to cancel the process before it finished.

I found that there is a dir `math` under `~/dirlinks/maths/`, and it seems that files under `.` are copied to `~/dirlinks/maths/math`, because I saw the files under `~/dirlinks/maths/math` also appear under `.`. But I don't understand because it is `mv` not `cp`. What happened when I run `mv math/ ~/dirlinks/maths/`?

Thanks.

Comment: If I try that I get: *mv: cannot move ‘math/’ to ‘../x/y/math’: Not a directory*. 

Are you sure the `~/dirlinks/maths/math` isn't a symlink? That would explain why the files appear under both paths.

Comment: `~/dirlinks/maths/math` is a dir not a symlink, created when I ran `mv`.

Comment: then your `mv` must be different from mine :)

Comment: Can you post the output of `cd -P ~/dirlinks/maths/math; pwd`?

Comment: @mikeserv: `/home/tim/dirlinks/maths/math`

Comment: And what about the other way - for ~/math?

Comment: @mikeserv: `bash: cd: /home/tim/math: No such file or directory`. Do you mean `cd -P ./math; pwd`? Its output is
`/windows-d/academic discipline/study objects/areas/formal systems/math`

Comment: Well, you've had a `mv` of some kind, then. Compare the inodes for the files directories that appear to be the same - if they differ and both are definitely not softlinks then you've done a copy somehow. Else you've got hardlinks. use `ls -i` to get the inodes. By the way, `mv` must copy if source/targets are on different file systems.

Comment: @mike: `~` and `/windows-d` are different file systems. Does that explain what has happened?

Comment: Yeah, that looks like why. a cross-file system `mv` equates to `cp source-dir/* target-dir; rm -rf source-dir`. Probably not *exactly* - dunno the order it would follow - but it is very close. So *hopefully* you interrupted only the copy bit? Check closely for missing files in `/windows-d`.

Comment: I interupted the copy process. Does that mean I can safely remove all the files under `~/dirlinks/maths/math` and the directory?

Comment: you could compare directories with `diff -arq . ~/dirlinks/maths/math`

Comment: @artm: when using `diff` on directories, it doesn't go into the content of each files under the directories, does it?

Comment: (my previous comment was incorrect): it does compare the contents of files, but only reports if files differ or absent under one of the directories with `-q` flag.

Answer (score 2):

Let's have a look at what your first command did: it created a symbolic link `math` in your current directory that points to the absolute path of the current directory. Lets inspect a bit closer:

```
user@host:/free$ ls -al /free
total 4
drwxrwxrwt  2 root root   40 Oct 14 10:29 .
drwxr-xr-x 24 root root 4096 Oct  1 22:28 ..
user@host:/free$ ln -vs /free math
‘math’ -> ‘/free’
user@host:/free$ ls -al /free
total 4
drwxrwxrwt  2 root root    60 Oct 14 10:29 .
drwxr-xr-x 24 root root  4096 Oct  1 22:28 ..
lrwxrwxrwx  1 user users    5 Oct 14 10:29 math -> /free
```

Now if you add some files to `$PWD` and perform the move:

```
user@host:/free$ touch a b
user@host:/free$ mv -vi math/ /tmp/Q
‘math/’ -> ‘/tmp/Q’
‘math/math’ -> ‘/tmp/Q/math’
‘math/b’ -> ‘/tmp/Q/b’
‘math/a’ -> ‘/tmp/Q/a’
removed ‘math/math’
removed ‘math/b’
removed ‘math/a’
mv: cannot remove ‘math/’: No such file or directory
```

Basically it moves the whole directory pointed to by `math` to the destination. Since it points to the current directory, it is completely moved where youtold it to. If you happened to be in somewhere directly above the destination, you it could have resulted in an interesting looping problem.